# enable_profile_selector for FB.Login() is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, unificationengine

I am trying to use Facebook login(javascript sdk of facebook) in my HTML page. I am able to get it to work. However, I need to provide the user the option to choose his/her profiles for my application(website) so that my application can post to the user's facebook pages(the ones that has been enabled for posting). Below is my code, please advise what I am missing.

```
<a class="btn" onclick="FB.login(function(response) {
   statusChangeCallback(response);
 },  {
    scope: 'publish_actions,publish_pages,manage_pages', 
    return_scopes: true,
    enable_profile_selector: true,
    profile_selector_ids: '1X86XXXXXXX3,250XXXXXXXXXX14'
});"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Facebook Account</a>
```

Also, I understand that the option profile_selector_ids is not mandatory as by default it should show all profiles for the user.

Appreciate your help in advance!

Thanks & Best Regards,
Anand Patil

Comment: Could you please try (with different set of the scopes) in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Same here I couldn't get `enable_profile_selector: true` to work, nothing shown up, please let me know if you have found a solution.

Comment: Also have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following scopes 
manage_pages, publish_stream, publish_actions

Comment: Yes, I have tried with all these scopes but its not working.

Comment: this scopes are outdated